# is there a way to mirror digital oceans unto a new github repo without using the old github repo(if it exists)

Tags: github, digital-ocean

a client of mine has deployed a project he was using GoDaddy then migrated to digital oceans, I want his Github repo but the one on go daddy is outdated and unusable, the DevOps that did the migrations is not responding, so I was thinking if there is a way to clone/mirror from a digital oceans droplet unto a new github repo

Answer (score 0):

Perhap you could use [hub](https://github.com/github/hub).

If you can `ssh` into the droplet, you just need to `cd` into the repo, install `hub` on the droplet, change the origin url to the one you want, and then run `hub create`. Don't forget to add the droplet's public ssh key to your github to allow `hub` to access it.